# Using a date picker in Zeppelin jdbc interpreter

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a set of charts in my Zeppelin notebook which fetch data from a database for a certain period of time using a jdbc interperter. What I'd like to do is to be able to choose a period which would apply to all the charts.

I can see that one could create an input field using a [Dynamic Form](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/manual/dynamicform.html) or even a date picker with [Angular](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/displaysystem/front-end-angular.html) (which would be even better). Is it possible to somehow use the chosen period in a jdbc interperter?

In the example given in [Apply Zeppelin Dynamic Forms](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/jdbc.html#apply-zeppelin-dynamic-forms) I can see how this could be done in one chart, but this is not what I want: to be able to define one field that will affect all of the charts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution (with angular intepreter):

first param (dependencies):

```
%angular
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

second param (daterangepicker) - change param ID :

```
%angular
<span>Date range picker:</span>
<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width:250px;">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
<p>
<p>
<input id="start" ng-model="start" style="visibility: hidden;"></input>
<input id="end" ng-model="end" style="visibility: hidden;"></input>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="z.angularBind('start',start,'fixme to param ID');z.angularBind('end',end,'fixme to param ID');"> Apply</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();
    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        $('#start').val(start.toISOString());
        $('#start').trigger('input'); // Use for Chrome/Firefox/Edge
        $('#start').trigger('change'); // Use for Chrome/Firefox/Edge + IE11
        $('#end').val(end.toISOString());
        $('#end').trigger('input'); // Use for Chrome/Firefox/Edge
        $('#end').trigger('change'); // Use for Chrome/Firefox/Edge + IE11
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
});
</script>
```

third param:

```
%jdbc
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE >= TO_TIMESTAMP('${start}') AND DATE <= TO_TIMESTAMP('${end}')
```

Comment: Works fine, but when I leave the browser and later load again the notebook the picker was gone until.re-run date's picker paragraph

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not seem to work. The date picker does not show up. I look in the console log and I found :
```
ReferenceError: moment is not defined

```

I tried to remove in the code any reference to the moment library but I was not able to make it work.Do you know how to inject it ?

Comment: Tried this out, after changing the dependencies, the date range is captured in the input field but it is not being passed to the other paragraph, I'm getting a NullPointer Exception, how do I solve this?